# Strange sharing warning in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace-for-business

When sharing some slides in Google Slides I get a message like

> This document contains United States - Driver's License Numbers. Are you sure you want to share it with people outside your organization?

However, the document does not seem to contain such numbers. Is this just a bug?

Specifically, this occurs when sharing [Openintro Statistics slides](https://www.openintro.org/stat/slides.php).

Comment: The same thing happened to me. I wonder why.

Comment: @Marvin Thanks for the bounty!

Comment: My pleasure! I was having the same exact problem, so I wanted answers.

Comment: Chat is here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88651/50-reputation-bounty-on-google-docs-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem has been ["passed on to the team"](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0kuMq54_RSqE/?hl=en) at Google.